# GetAudio Plugin for MvvmCross

Tags: ios, plugins, touch, mvvmcross, exporter

I'm developing an plugin for MvvmCross to GetAudio from the device. But I'm getting an error in the Touch implementation. I've already took a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650607/avassetexportsession-fails-every-time-error-12780), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529250/avassetexportsession-outputfile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653241/get-error-code-11843-while-exporting-mp3-file-in-ipod-library-since-ios-5-1).

But nothing fixed my problem.

Well, so far I have:

```
        var audioDelegate = new AudioDelegate();
        audioDelegate.AudioAvailable = ProcessAudio;
        mediaPicker = new MPMediaPickerController(); 
        mediaPicker.Delegate = audioDelegate;
        mediaPicker.AllowsPickingMultipleItems = false;
        modalHost.PresentModalViewController (mediaPicker, true);
```

To start the picker from audio, where AudioDelegate is:

```
    private class AudioDelegate : MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate
    {
        public EventHandler<MvxAudioRecorderEventArgs> AudioAvailable;

        public override void MediaItemsPicked (MPMediaPickerController sender, MPMediaItemCollection mediaItemCollection)
        {
            if (mediaItemCollection.Count < 1) 
            {
                return;
            }
            MvxAudioRecorderEventArgs eventArg = new MvxAudioRecorderEventArgs (mediaItemCollection.Items [0].AssetURL);
            AudioAvailable (this, eventArg);
        }
    }
```

And then in ProcessAudio:

```
    private void ProcessMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var assetURL = e.MediaUrl;
        NSDictionary dictionary = null;
        var assetExtension = e.MediaUrl.Path.Split ('.') [1];

        var songAsset = new AVUrlAsset (assetURL, dictionary);
        var exporter = new AVAssetExportSession (songAsset, AVAssetExportSession.PresetPassthrough.ToString ());
        exporter.OutputFileType = (assetExtension == "mp3") ? "com.apple.quicktime-movie" : AVFileType.AppleM4A;
        var manager = new NSFileManager ();

        var count = 0;
        string filePath = null;
        do 
        {
            var extension = "mov";//( NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(( CFStringRef)AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);
            var fileNameNoExtension = "AUD_" + Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ();
            var fileName = string.Format ("{0}({1})", fileNameNoExtension, count);
            filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/";
            filePath = filePath + fileName + "." + extension;
            count++;

        } while (manager.FileExists (filePath));

        var outputURL = new NSUrl (filePath);//should be something in objective C... => [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

        exporter.OutputUrl = outputURL;


        exporter.ExportAsynchronously ( () =>
            {
                var exportStatus = exporter.Status;
                switch (exportStatus) 
                {
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Unknown:
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed: 
                    {
                        //remove the .mov from file and make it available for callback mediaAvailable()...
                        break;
                    }
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Waiting:
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Exporting:
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed: 
                    default:
                    {
                        var exportError = exporter.Error;
                        if(assumeCancelled != null)
                        {
                            assumeCancelled();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });


        mediaPicker.DismissViewController(true, () => { });
        modalHost.NativeModalViewControllerDisappearedOnItsOwn();
    }
```

But it is always with Status.Failed with error:

```
        LocalizedDescription: The operation could not be completed

        Description: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 
        "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x1476cce0 
        {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, 
        NSUnderlyingError=0x1585da90 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
        (OSStatus error -12780.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error
        occurred (-12780)}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in regard,

Comment: Are you playing remote content? It might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101380/avurlasset-refuses-to-load-video where AVURLAsset fails when using specific paths to resource. Maybe this is a clue.

Comment: Hey cheesebaron, not really. The file is already inside the device. It is in the Music app, locally. It is saying .mov in the code, just because it was a try in the links I pasted here. But the file I'm trying is an mp3 from MusicPlayerChooser. Any clue?

Comment: Edited with solution...

Comment: Put the solution as an answer and mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. As I thought the error was in the outputURL file.

Changed it to:

```
        var count = 0;
        string filePath = null;
        do 
        {
            var extension = "mp3.mov";//( NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(( CFStringRef)AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);
            var fileNameNoExtension = "AUD_" + Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ();
            var fileName = (count == 0) ? fileNameNoExtension : string.Format ("{0}({1})", fileNameNoExtension, count);
            filePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath + "/../tmp/" + fileName; /* HERE WAS THE FIRST PROBLEM, USE NSBUNDLE... */
            filePath = filePath + fileName + "." + extension;
            count++;

        } while (manager.FileExists (filePath));
        var outputURL = NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath); /* HERE WAAS THE SECOND PROBLEM, CREATE IT WITH FROMFILENAME INSTEAD OF NEW... */
```

And then in the export, just remove the .mov extension...

```
        var withoutMOVPath = outputURL.Path.Remove(outputURL.Path.Length - 4);
        NSError error = null;
        manager.Move (outputURL.Path, withoutMOVPath, out error);

            if(error != null && assumeCancelled != null)
            {
                assumeCancelled();
                return;
            }

        var mediaStream = new FileStream (withoutMOVPath, FileMode.Open);
        mediaAvailable (mediaStream);
        break;
```