# Supported video formats iOS7 UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

My app has video recording functionality. I want to know if I can record in wmv or avi formats. What formats are supported?

Comment: Think mov rather than wmv/avi.

Answer (score 2):

Open [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) and go tot the Video Technologies section, it will give you some information about video formats, resolution, etc...

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried reading that before I asked the question. I don't know enough about iOS development to find my answer in the documentation. I want to end up with the video in a format that can be supported by windows media player. I have so far figured out how to record in MOV format and I tried playing it in windows media player but it is not supported.

Comment: So you want to export the videos off the phone? At the end of the day it doesn't matter what you take the video in, I guess you can convert it when you are ready to export, to an MOV or an AVI, or whatever it is. Also, doesn't windows media player support MP4?

Comment: Yes, windows media player does support MP4. How can I end up with the video format in mp4? Do I just change the extension or need to do a conversion?

Comment: Find out what format the videos are saved in, I'm not sure, but it's probably .m4v then you need to convert the video. I just found this have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282672/record-save-and-or-convert-video-in-mp4-format. Good luck!