# Convert video in mp4 format

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am newbie and trying to create an app that records video or select video from library, than I am uploading that video to the web. But this files are not playing in some android device. So i want to convert it to **mp4** format.

Hence i want to ask that how to convert saved `mov` to `mp4` in `objective-C`?

FYI i have researched alot but not found any helpful information.

**Here's my code:**

```
- (void)openCamera {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
} 


- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath))
        {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self, nil, nil);
        }
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record, save and/or convert video in mp4 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282672/record-save-and-or-convert-video-in-mp4-format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out [my so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282672/record-save-and-or-convert-video-in-mp4-format/20283319#20283319). It may help you

You are doing right thing.. Now you need to convert this mov file to mp4 as below.

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
 {
   if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath))
   {
         NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
         NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
         NSString *videoPath1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xyz.mov",docDir];
         NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
         NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
         [videoData writeToFile:videoPath1 atomically:NO];
       //  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self, nil, nil);
   }
 }

    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath1] options:nil];
    NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];

    if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
    {
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xyz.mp4", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
        NSLog(@"videopath of your mp4 file = %@",videoPath);  // PATH OF YOUR .mp4 FILE
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

      //  CMTime start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 600);
      //  CMTime duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(3.0, 600);           
      //  CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration);            
      //   exportSession.timeRange = range;        
      //  UNCOMMENT ABOVE LINES FOR CROP VIDEO   
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

            switch ([exportSession status]) {

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);

                    break;

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:

                    NSLog(@"Export canceled");

                    break;

                default:

                    break;

            }
             UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, self, nil, nil);
            [exportSession release];

        }];

    }
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```