# Is it possible to set maximum size of video like videoMaximumDuration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to capture & choose video file from library. 
I have to restrict user to capture only video whose size is less than or equal to `5MB`.
Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Hello..you got any solution regarding this?

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34370289/3908884
I think you have to compress video before sending it to the server..

Comment: Hello..you got any solution regarding this?