# How to change video resolution in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video-capture, avassetexportsession

Is there a way to export a video with resolution **480 x 960** ?  I know there are libraries for this but I'd rather do it without installing more pods on my project if possible.

I am converting a captured video in .MOV to .MP4. I used the method suggested on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354689/swift-how-to-record-video-in-mp4-format-with-uiimagepickercontroller).

The available options from [AVAssetExport](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/preset/1620471-hd1920x1080) are these:

```
AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality  
AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality 
AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality 
AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality  
AVAssetExportPreset640x480 
AVAssetExportPreset960x540  
AVAssetExportPreset1280x720 
AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080  
AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
```

Is this the correct approach if the exported video is MP4? The documentation for AVAssetExportSession says this is for quicktime movies so I am a bit confused about this.

```
    func exportVideo(inputurl: URL,
                 presetName: String = AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality,
                 outputFileType: AVFileType = .mp4,
                 fileExtension: String = "mp4",
                 then completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void)
{
    let asset = AVAsset(url: inputurl)


    let filename = filePath.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension(fileExtension).lastPathComponent
    outputURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

    if let session = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: presetName) {
        session.outputURL = outputURL
        session.outputFileType = outputFileType

        session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        session.exportAsynchronously {
            switch session.status {
            case .completed:
                completion(self.outputURL)
            case .cancelled:
                debugPrint("Video export cancelled.")
                completion(nil)
            case .failed:
                let errorMessage = session.error?.localizedDescription ?? "n/a"
                debugPrint("Video export failed with error: \(errorMessage)")
                completion(nil)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: check this code, it may be helpful for you.
https://gist.github.com/zrxq/9817265

Answer (score 1):

You must transform video tranck and video composition to your export session...

You have to do something like this:

```
    //transform video
    let rotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
    videoTrack.preferredTransform = rotationTransform;

    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    layerInstruction.setTransform(videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)

    let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
    videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]

    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.instructions = [videoCompositionInstruction]
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize

    //saving...
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else { return }
    //exportSession.outputURL = your output url
    exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
```

Comment: thank you! I used this method but for some reason it only changes the size of the canvas but not the video

Comment: ok, than try to change layerInstruction transform like this:
layerInstruction.setTransform(rotationTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)

this code is not tested, because i need extra job to test... play around it.