# Send Core Data object to post api Alamofire multipartFormData

Tags: swift, core-data, alamofire, multipartform-data

I have a screen on my app that I get some fields and save on my object Order. This object is my Core Data Object. After saving it, I need to send it to my backend through Alamofire POST multipartFormData.
The problem is that this is a Core Data Object (not Codable) and I need to send Data type on multipartFormData. How can I convert my object to Data? Is there another way of doing it?

What I've done:

```
let order = Order(context: DatabaseController.getContext())
order.orderItem = orderItem
order.product = product
order.value = value
order.date = date
```

Alamofire part:

```
Alamofire.upload (
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                multipartFormData.append(order, withName: "order")
            },
            to: url,
            headers: headers,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
```

The problem is how to put my object Order inside multipartFormData?
Could anyone help me please?

**Updated:**

Ok, sending the whole object didn't work, my api didn't accept, so I made a specific json only with the fields needed and turned it a Data type:
(PS: files are Data type from images user choose, even from camera or gallery)

```
var files = Dictionary<Data, String>()
var jsonFiles = [[String: String]]()
var jsonOrder = [String: Any]()

for file in files {
    let dict : [String: String] = [ "orderImageIdLocal": uuidOrderImageIdLocal,
                                    "orderItemAnalysisIdLocal": uuidAnalysisIdLocal,
                                    "urlImageLocal": "\(imageId).jpg"]
    jsonFiles.append(dict)
}
jsonOrder = [ "reason": "\(textViewReason)",
                          "orderImagess": jsonFiles,
                          "orderAnalysisId": "",
                          "orderIdLocal": "\(uuidAnaliseIdLocal)",
                          "orderId": "\(orderId ?? "")",
                          "typeSolicitation": "\(typeSolicitation)"]
```

Then I convert it to Data type like you said and send to Alamofire like above:

```
let orderData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonOrder, options: .prettyPrinted) {
```

My problem now is that my api expect a zip file with those images user took from camera or gallery. So I am trying to use [ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation). I still don't know how to zip it and send. Should I zip each picture as Data type? Then transform zip file into Data type so I can send through `multipartFormData.append`?

I have tried: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223368/how-to-upload-zip-file-to-server-with-multipartformdata-in-ios-swift) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977486/how-to-upload-zip-data-with-alamofire)

Comment: Do you have access to the source code your api method on server? Can you post that? In that case it will be clear what your api exactly expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the code as an extension of `NSManagedObject` which creates dictionary from the attributes name.

```
extension NSManagedObject {
  func toData() -> Data? {
    let keys = Array(self.entity.attributesByName.keys)
    let dict = self.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: keys)
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
        return jsonData
    }
    catch{}
    return nil
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let jsonData = order.toData()
multipartFormData.append(jsonData, withName: "order")
```

Comment: Ok, your solution works. But my logic is wrong. I need to send a package of images and this order object. How can I do that? When I use Alamofire.request, I can send "parameters" as json object. But sending a package of images I should use upload, right? So I don't have parameters. Since I still need to send some images. Could you help please?

Comment: Can you update your question with details and your server restapi functions, (what your is expecting to receive)? and i will try to help you