# Compressing videos programmatically (iOS)

Tags: ios, video, compression

I want some sample code for compressing videos in IOS programmatically, I have already tried with this [iPhone:Programmatically compressing recorded video to share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share)

which give the same file size before and after compressing the video.

Please let me know what wrong with this code [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to log the asset, if asset is null please check your url.