# How to Compress video file in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to compress mp4 video file before uploading to server. I am uploading images to server by scalling it.But in case of larger video files it takes long time to upload.Is there any way to compress video before uploading it.Video files in iphone is very big even for 1min video.Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone:Programmatically compressing recorded video to share?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share)

Answer (score -3):

There are a number of apps available on the iStore that will do this for you:
http://videoconverterapp.com/
http://www.videoslimmerapp.com/reduce-iphone-video-size.html